# Laravel 5 dont auto logged in after registration

Tags: php, laravel

How to make **not auto logged in after registration** completed in Laravel 5.
I use basic authentication from [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication)

I have not already re-code the postRegister() from AuthController.php and just using the basic of Laravel without changing anything.

This is my AuthController.php

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ]);
}

protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

This is my Routes

```
Route::get('auth/register', ['middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister']);
Route::post('auth/register', ['middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister']);
```

And this is my registration form

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('auth/register') }}">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}

    <div>
        Name
        <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}">
    </div>

    <div>
        Email
        <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
    </div>

    <div>
        Password
        <input type="password" name="password">
    </div>

    <div>
        Confirm Password
        <input type="password" name="password_confirmation">
    </div>

    <div>
        <button type="submit">Register</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Handle a registration request for the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function postRegister(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }

    // Commenting this line should help.
    Auth::login($this->create($request->all())); 

    return redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

This is the function you're looking for. Just edit/overwrite this according to your wills.

Comment: I have already commenting Auth::login line, then get the error 



`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::all()`

Answer (score 1):

For any one looking for a **Laravel 5.2** solution to this little snag, put this in your `AuthController.php` file, remember to include/use the request in the top of the controller

*app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php*

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
...

/**
 * Handle a registration request for the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function register(Request $request)
{   
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );  
    }   

    $this->create($request->all());

    return redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just `Auth::logout();` in your postRegister function (when successful i.e. after validator passes) and then `Redirect::to();` some other page, perhaps you want to carry out email validation or something else prior to being able to login.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the comment.

I only use the registration by manual from authentication of another user only. Maybe you can see that's why I protect the routes.

Thank you!

Comment: Refer to Ozan's answer and simply comment out the Auth::login line, this file should sit in the Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ Folder - This should also work if you have a already logged in user creating another user... I assume you are worried about the already logged in user creating an account then being logged in as this account?

Comment: the registration are available from someone who registering them with form. So new user cannot access the url and register for themselves.

Comment: @sprintcar78a Yes you are correct exactly. I should stay with the user current login after registrating new user, not logged in as the user I have made.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
* Handle a registration request for the application.
*
* @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
* @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
*/
public function postRegister(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }

    Auth::login($this->create($request->all())); // Comment this line

    return redirect('/'); // Change the redirection
}
```

Comment: if you comment out `Auth::login($this->create($request->all()));` then the create function wont be hit, and the user wont be created.

Answer (score 0):

Open your register controller and override register method, which you can find in vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
  use RegistersUsers;
  protected $redirectTo = '/'; // redirect after user registration

  public function register(Request $request)
  {
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    $this->guard()->login($user);   // comment this line to stop autologin after registration

    return redirect($this->redirectPath());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can override `postRegister()` method for disable auto login, `login()` only call when the active field is true.

your `postRegister()` will be something like :

```
public function postRegister(Request $request)
{

    // validation

    // insert record in user entity

    // check user is active or not

    if ($request->get('active')) {
        $this->auth->login($user);
    }

    // do further as you need
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a quick fix. I am not sure if it is the best solution, totally new with Laravel. So, what I did is I went in the `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth` folder and opened the `RedrectsUsers.php` file, and I changed the `redirectPath()` function. So what my function looks like now is:

```
public function redirectPath() {return property_exists($this, 'redirectTo') ?$this->redirectTo : '/login';}
```

Basically, I replaced the `home` with `login`. Hope it's alright. Waiting on comments, suggestions or any other observations. Good luck lads.